# How to run webpack when using ng build instead of ng serve?

Tags: angular, debugging, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have a .NET web application hosted in IIS. This .NET web application hosts an Angular application. This causes that these applications(.NET and Angular)are served on the same port by IIS. **They need to be served on the same port because they use the same session cookie.** Also they're part of the same CI/CD pipeline and there are other reasons.

However this causes that I can't debug typescript, only javascript is available, through chrome as I don't have `webpack` available in the sources(I have the sourcemaps). The reason for that is that I use `ng build` instead of `ng serve` to build my app. If I use `ng serve` the Angular app is served on different port and I have all the typescript sources available in the Chrome in `webpack` directory in the sources in developer tools. However then I can't use Angular app because I can't obtain the cookie for this port.

**Question**: What command use when using `ng build` to use webpack to bundle my sources in order to debug TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

`ng build --dev` may help to build scripts without minified

Comment: Not if it's not configured in his packeage.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new angular cli project and then do `ng eject`, your webpack configuration file will appear on your solution and your `package.json` file scripts command will change as follows:

`ng serve` => `wepack-dev-server`,
`ng build` => `wepack`

so the actual command that `angular cli` call is `wepack` which will bundle your application on the dist folder.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you're not far with your project.

https://angular.io/generated/zips/webpack/webpack.zip

This is a starter Angular app with webpack.
If hit **npm run build** will make a dist with all files you need. Then you copy those files to the location of your IIS website folder.

If you add webpack on a current project good luck webpack is very sctrict and can cost alot of days to make it running.

Also note that IIS will give conflicts with the base href of angular "/". There is a guide on google to fix it.